# Spring Kafka failed to resolve className

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to send a data object from one spring service to another service using kafka.

The problem is that kafka is not able to resolve the className and hence is unable to map the consumber's class to the producer's class.
Following is the error message:

`Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

I have tried to map the class using the following property:

For the producer: `spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=event:com.ankit.orderservice.event.OrderPlacedEvent`

For the consumer: `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping: event:com.ankit.OrderPlacedEvent`

Comment: You need to show the rest of your configuration and code, and the complete stack trace.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping: event:com.ankit.OrderPlacedEvent`, should be `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping= event:com.ankit.OrderPlacedEvent`

Big picture: when the producer creates new messages, the `__TypeId__` header includes information about the java class. The consumer verifies that you try to deserliaze into the same class, which fails because of the different package names. Options to fix this:

1. move the message classes to a module that you include in both your projects (producer, consumer)
2. map types (this is what you tried): https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types